# Get the week number of a given date (Week Start from Sunday)

Tags: sql-server, datetime, weekday

I have to calculate Week number of a given date, First day of week is `Sunday`.

here is what I am doing.

```
 DECLARE @Range_StartDate AS DATETIME  = '2017-01-01'
SELECT    @Range_StartDate,DATEPART(WEEK, @Range_StartDate)
```

Just for an example, the year 2016, the first week starts from 3rd January having a first week day is Sunday, I want to supply '2016-01-01' and it should return 2016-01-03 the first week of the year .

Comment: Ok, your results should be `'2017-01-01 00:00:00', 1`. Is it something else?

Comment: As the first week of Year 2017 starts from 1st January if i set offset of weekday from Sunday.

Comment: @DareDevil 3rd of January the first day of the week? In what calendar?

Comment: In my calendar 2017-01-01 was sunday. Perhaps you are talking about a different year?

Comment: Sorry people, I was telling you of year 2016.

Comment: Ok, so what do you expect to get back? `ISO_WEEK` returns 53 (52 for 2017), `WEEK` returns 1.

Comment: `I want to supply '2016-01-01' and it should return 2016-01-03 the first week of the year` vs `I have to calculate Week number of a given date` those statement do not correspond - do you need to return a date or a week number? According to  ISO 8601 but 1st day is Sunday?

Comment: Yes. Suppose I have 10 years starting from 2005 and I want to get the first week's first day date.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give 2016-01-01 as input and want 2016-01-03 as output then you can write something as below.

```
 DECLARE @Range_StartDate AS DATETIME  = '2016-01-01'
 Declare @Days_ToAdd AS Int =  8-DATEPART(dw, @Range_StartDate) 
 if @Days_ToAdd = 7
 set @Days_ToAdd =0 

SELECT    @Range_StartDate,DATEADD(day,@Days_ToAdd,@Range_StartDate)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get first day of week.
For example, 
Date : 2017-01-01, First day will be 2017-01-03 00:00:00.000

```
DECLARE @Date datetime
DECLARE @Year int = YEAR('2017-01-01')
SET @Date = DATEADD(YEAR, @Year - 1900, 0)

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, (@@DATEFIRST - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Date) + (8 - @@DATEFIRST) * 2) % 6, @Date)
```